# MySql--Order by is "breaking" my query?

Tags: mysql

So, I have a query that I want to execute, and once it's done I want the results sorted by Time desc.

However when I do that it only spits out a single result... here's what I'm seeing:

First a Query with no sorting:

[image: No sorting]

Second is my query with the order by added in:
[image: All the results have been added into a single row]

Can someone help me understand what's going on and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you order by `\`Time\`` rather than `Time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queries are different.

Variables are evaluated after the `order by` clause.  As a result, a different set of rows satisfy the `having` clause.

To fix the problem, put your query -- WITHOUT the order by -- into a subquery.  Do the selection you want and then `order by` in the outer query.

EDIT:

I'm not going to retype your query from your pasted images.  The structure of the query is:

```
select *
from (<your query here>) s
order by Time desc
limit 5
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with this answer?  I'm not sure of the syntax to use to make this into a query / subquery.

Answer (score 1):

try this, has the special quotes around column name

```
order by `time` desc
```