# Mysql: Gap detection query not detecting gaps

Tags: php, mysql

It seems as though my gap detection is just picking up whatever I set as the timedifference and doing it every interval based on that.

So here's an explanation of my data structure and what I'm after:

I have a database that's set up like this:

```
(Schema Name)
Historical
     -CID      int UQ AI NN 
     -ID       Int PK
     -Location Varchar(255)
     -Status   Varchar(255)
     -Time     datetime
```

My data comes in looking something like this (example 5 rows for selected ID)

```
 433275 | 97  | MyLocation | OK | 2013-08-20 13:05:54
 433275 | 97  | MyLocation | OK | 2013-08-20 13:00:54
 433275 | 97  | MyLocation | OK | 2013-08-20 12:25:54
 433275 | 97  | MyLocation | OK | 2013-08-20 12:20:54
 433275 | 97  | MyLocation | OK | 2013-08-20 12:15:54
```

In the case above you'll notice that I'm missing data from 12:25:54 -> 13:00 for ID 97.   I am trying to write a report that will tell me the: Start of downtime,  Duration of DownTime, and End of Downtime (which I've been handling in php by adding timediff to Time)

Here's my code (php -> mysql) (non-working) as it stands now:

```
        select *from (
            SELECT
            y.*,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevDT, `Time`) AS timedifference,
            @prevDT := `Time`
            FROM ddHistorical y,
            (SELECT @prevDT:=(SELECT MIN(`Time`) FROM ddHistorical)) vars
            Where ID  = '". mysql_real_escape_string($ID)."'
            HAVING timedifference > 16
          ) s
          order by Time desc
          Limit 25";
```

Comment: You need to put the `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery, not the outer query.

Comment: If it's in the subquery, it groups everything into a single result, see question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410334/mysql-order-by-is-breaking-my-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  y.*,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevDT, `Time`) AS timedifference,
            @prevDT := `Time`
            FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM ddHistorical
                  WHERE ID = '97'
                  ORDER BY `Time`) y,
                 (SELECT @prevDT:=(SELECT MIN(`Time`) FROM ddHistorical)) vars) z
WHERE timedifference > 16
LIMIT 25
```

I'm actually not sure why the outermost level is needed. I tried without it (i.e. starting with `SELECT y.*`) and using `HAVING timedifference > 16`. For some reason, this reported a single row with `timedifference = 45`. But if I removed that `HAVING` clause, it showed all the rows, with the gap reported as 35 minutes. Usually, there's no difference between

```
SELECT ... HAVING <cond>
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) WHERE <cond>
```

I'm not sure why this query violates the rule -- I suspect it has something to do with the user-variables.

EDIT:

I think I've figured out why it didn't work with `HAVING`. MySQL is apparently evaluating that condition as soon as it calculates the `timedifference` column for each row, and discarding the row. When `timedifference <= 16`, it doesn't bother calculating the rest of the columns in the `SELECT` clause, so it never does `@prevDT := Time`. So until it gets past that condition, it's always comparing with `MIN(Time)`.

Moving the `timedifference` check into an outer query forces it to calculate all the differences before filtering.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa1fe/15)

Comment: This works exactly how I wanted it to, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
"
SELECT y.*,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, y.prevDT, y.`Time`) AS timedifference
  FROM (SELECT w.*, (SELECT MAX(x.`Time`)
                       FROM ddHistorical x
                      WHERE x.ID = w.ID
                        AND x.`Time` < w.`Time`) AS prevDT
          FROM ddHistorical w
         WHERE w.ID  = '". mysql_real_escape_string($ID)."') y
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, y.prevDT, y.`Time`) > 16
 ORDER BY y.`Time` DESC
 LIMIT 25";
```