# select rows with particular row-number values

Tags: mysql, having-clause

Here's a test table with 20 items.

```
create table test (id int not null primary key);
insert into test values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19);
```

I can add a row number column like this (fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dade4/3):

```
select id, @r:=@r+1 r
from test a
join (select @r:=0) b;
```

Then I try to get the first 10 items with a `HAVING` clause (fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dade4/4):

```
select id, @r:=@r+1 r
from test a
join (select @r:=0) b
having r <= 10;
```

Here's unexpected result:

```
ID| R
------
0 | 2
1 | 4
2 | 6
3 | 8
4 | 10
```

Why is this, and how do to retrieve rows where r is between 1 and 10?

(I'm not using LIMIT because in a different query, I needed to select the top n items for each category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other answers, `having` is not the way, but if you need to use it then:

```
select id, @r:=@r+1 r
  from test a
  join (select @r:=0) b
having @r+1 <= 10;
```

Here the [demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dade4/8).

There reason why you get the wrong results is because MySql evaluates twice the alias r (in the select and in the having), so `@r:=@r+1` is executed twice.

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` doesn't make sense unless you're in an aggregate (`SUM()`, `COUNT()`, `GROUP BY`) query.

You need to encapsulate your rownumbering in a proper subquery (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dade4/6/0).

```
select id, r
   from (select id, @r:=@r+1 r
         from test a
         join (select @r:=0) b
   ) as q
where r <= 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when I was answering this question:

[Mysql: Gap detection query not detecting gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413654/mysql-gap-detection-query-not-detecting-gaps/18413819#18413819)

MySQL apparently performs the `HAVING` test as it's generating the results when there's no aggregation being done, and this causes some short-circuiting.

The solution is to use a subquery.

```
select id, r
   from (select id, @r:=@r+1 r
         from test a
         join (select @r:=0) b
   ) as q
where r <= 10;
```